# sympy : compute simple expected value takes a lot of time

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to compute an expected value from a simple model based on random variables.
I use `Normal` distribution only because I don't know another way to define a random variable (without specifying the underlying distribution). Basically the '_m' symbols represent the mean of the random distributions. In the end I combine some of these variables, and compute the expected value of a product. Using simple algebra one can quickly compute the result, but sympy needs about 2 minutes (eventually gives the right result, returning True).

```py
import sympy as sp
from sympy.stats import P, E, variance, Die, Normal, Poisson

G_m, L, Ad, tau, Omega_m, eta_m = sp.symbols('\\bar{G}, L, A_d, tau, \\bar{\Omega}, \\bar{\eta}')

sigma_i_vh     = sp.symbols('\sigma_{i_{vh}}'     , positive=True)
sigma_eta_vh   = sp.symbols('\sigma_{\eta_{vh}}'  , positive=True)
sigma_Omega_v  = sp.symbols('\sigma_{\Omega_v}'   , positive=True)
sigma_Omega_h  = sp.symbols('\sigma_{\Omega_h}'   , positive=True)
sigma_Omega_vh = sp.symbols('\sigma_{\Omega_{vh}}', positive=True)
sigma_G_t      = sp.symbols('\sigma_{G_t}'        , positive=True)
sigma_G_v      = sp.symbols('\sigma_{G_v}'        , positive=True)
sigma_G_h      = sp.symbols('\sigma_{G_h}'        , positive=True)
sigma_G_tv     = sp.symbols('\sigma_{G_{tv}}'     , positive=True)
sigma_G_th     = sp.symbols('\sigma_{G_{th}}'     , positive=True)
sigma_G_vh     = sp.symbols('\sigma_{G_{vh}}'     , positive=True)
sigma_G_tvh    = sp.symbols('\sigma_{G_{tvh}}'    , positive=True)

i_vh_random     = Normal('i_{vh}',      0, sigma_i_vh)
eta_vh_random   = Normal('\eta_{vh}',   0, sigma_eta_vh)
Omega_v_random  = Normal('\Omega_v',    0, sigma_Omega_v)
Omega_h_random  = Normal('\Omega_h',    0, sigma_Omega_h)
Omega_vh_random = Normal('\Omega_{vh}', 0, sigma_Omega_vh)
G_t_random      = Normal('G_{t}',       0, sigma_G_t)
G_v_random      = Normal('G_{v}',       0, sigma_G_v)
G_h_random      = Normal('G_{h}',       0, sigma_G_h)
G_tv_random     = Normal('G_{tv}',      0, sigma_G_tv)
G_th_random     = Normal('G_{th}',      0, sigma_G_th)
G_vh_random     = Normal('G_{vh}',      0, sigma_G_vh)
G_tvh_random    = Normal('G_{tvh}',     0, sigma_G_tvh)

eta = eta_m + eta_vh_random
Omega = Omega_m + Omega_v_random + Omega_h_random + Omega_vh_random
phi_xy = L*Ad*tau*eta*Omega
G = G_m + G_t_random + G_v_random + G_h_random + G_tv_random + G_th_random + G_vh_random + G_tvh_random 

E(G*phi_xy) == G_m * Ad * L * tau * eta_m *Omega_m
# variance(G*phi_xy)
```

My end goal is to compute the variance of the product, using `variance(G*phi_xy)`, but sympy never returns a result - I guess it takes way more steps than the expected value, which seems already quite long to compute.

I am wondering if something is ill-defined that make sympy extra-steps in the computation, or if it is 'normal' that sympy takes so long to compute ?

Python : 3.9.7 (default, Sep 16 2021, 08:50:36) \n[Clang 10.0.0 ]
Sympy : 1.11.1
on a mac 3,1 GHz Intel Core i7 dual-core

Comment: Can you please provide the code of computation of the variance of the product, so we can analyze why it is slow.

Comment: @Caridorc thanks, I added a comment in the python code

Comment: This doesn't look simple: `Expectation(A_d*L*tau*(\bar{\eta} + \eta_{vh})*(\bar{\Omega} + \Omega_h + \Omega_v + \Omega_{vh})*(\bar{G} + G_{h} + G_{th} + G_{tvh} + G_{tv} + G_{t} + G_{vh} + G_{v}))`

Comment: Well the model knows that `A_d`, `L` and `tau` are scalars so can be factorized outside of the expectation, then expanding the products gives a sum of 2*4*8=64 products of 3 variables, most of whom has an expected value of 0 since only the first term has non-0 expected value - so I thought a computer would resolve this pretty quickly. You can see the sum using `(G*phi_xy).expand()`, which is not that long and complicated to solve (you can do this by hand pretty quickly knowing that any `_t/v/h/th/tv/vh/tvh` has an expected value of 0).

Comment: Yes, I played around with things like `expand`, and found it can factor out a common expression, etc,  And superficially steps like that seem to improve the `expectation` time (I didn't try a formal `timeit`).  But apparently that doesn't help with the variance.  Time complexity of this kind of symbolic processing is much harder to figure out (compared to `numpy` array stuff).  But you can read the `stats` documentation just as well as I can, so I'll pass on further exploration.

Comment: For completeness, `timeit` on `E((G*phi_xy).expand())` gives me 2.98s, while `E(G*phi_xy)` gives me 13.3s